# 3389 Port Forwarding

Tags: port, remote-desktop, port-forwarding, remote-access

I'm trying to forward a 3389 port from a computer over to a router, then to a Modem/Router so I can access this through a public IP address. I'm trying to work backwards here and so far I can only get the 3389 port on my computer forward to the router. My pc is running on a dynamic ip address.

I can Remote into 3389 through my pc's ipaddress or through the WAN IP (coming from the router that is tied to the PC), but that's it. What can I do to get my port open to the public?

On my Tenda..
The WAN IP is..
10.1.10.141

That's a class A ip address if I'm correct. Looks like a private address. I'm with Comcast. Aren't I suppose to port forward it somehow from the router that is connected to my PC to the Modem/Router that is tied to Comcast first before I can make it public? Not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably better asked on the Super User Stack Exchange since it seemingly applies to a home Internet connection.

You're correct that a 10.0.0.0/8 range is reserved as private. Perhaps Comcast is using Carrier-Grade NAT. If that's the case, they should be using addresses in the 100.64.0.0/10 range, but it's not required. In any case, 10.1.10.141 is not routable on the Internet, so you'll be unable to do port forwards unless somebody else in the Comcast network behind the same CGN as you is the one who wants to get in.

You may be able to ask Comcast to give you a real IP address instead. Good luck.